# Pockels effect/Kerr effect

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, quantum-optics, non-linear-optics

In Pockels electro-optic effect, change in Electric field produces change in refractive index/ birefringence. Moreover this effect becomes electric field squared in the case of Kerr effect. If we increase the electric field more for example 3 ,4 , 5 times . we will observe the same phenomenon of Kerr effect or is it something else ?

Comment: The dependence of polarisation on an applied field is a series expansion with lots of components of the susceptibility of the material in question. In linear optics only a linear dependence on the susceptability if observed, but higher order effects use higher orders of the susceptibility. The Kerr effect is a second order effect which is why the effect varies with the electric field squared. I can't write more as I'm at work and can't put down the full maths here, but if I remember when I get home I will do.